# Sign In With Google not working on different devices than emulator

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I can't go through first activity which requires user to log in via google account, since everything is working fine in 100% on emulator on computer i made this project, it does not work on any other computer / device.

It just shows currently logged accounts when I click the button, but when I'm choosing one of them, nothing happens, just pop up windows dissapears.

I am using Firebase Authentication.

Any ideas how is this possible and how to get through?

onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    final GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Error!");
                }
            })
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, googleSignInOptions)
            .build();

    SignInButton signInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        }
    });

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if(firebaseUser != null){
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Thanks,
Maciej

Comment: Firebase Auth requires a compatible version of Google Play services be installed on the device.  Look in logcat during app initialization for this message: `W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date`.

Comment: What about APK on mobile phone? I have the newest version of Google Play Services on my mobile phone and still this isn't working

Comment: If you don't see the warning message, the problem must be something else.  Differences in Google Play services often explain situations where the same code works on one device or emulator but not another.  Apparently, not the case here.

Comment: I found a solution how to Run project on another computer - When I copied project to my laptop and ran it it automaticly created a new SHA1 for this device so I just added a fingerprint in Firebase and it works fine now. Just wondering, how to make it work for mobile device